What is the proper formatting of very low p values?
Generally, I believe in giving exact p values rather than something like " p < 0.05".  But, sometimes, the p value is extremely low, on the order, say, of $10^{-10}$ or even lower. Under what circumstances should we a) Round it off and say "$p < 10^{-5}$" or b) Give the full estimate in scientific notation e.g. "$p = 3.46\times 10^{-7}$"?

Does this answer your question? How should tiny $p$-values be reported? (and why does R put a minimum on 2.22e-16?)

That's going to be (a) very context dependent and (b) a matter of opinion. It's not really a statistical issue but one of communication and convention (and the extent to which the p-value being reported might be at all meaningful. If you're so deep in the tail the details you could gloss over at p~0.05 as not making much difference now make a big difference). I'm not sure there's a single good, clear answer for this.

Peter, this is actually a good question. However, I have to agree with Glen_b here. There is no single correct answer for this rather it's "a matter of opinion", imo. But +1.

The relationship between p-values and the the "strength" of evidence in data against the null hypothesis is multi-dimensional and wildly non-linear (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0081), but it seems reasonable to assume that it is at least roughly logarithmic. That suggests to me that is an observed p-value is less than, say $10^{-4}$ then it would probably be good enough to say, for example that p$\approx{10^{-6.5}}$ rather than $3.46\times 10^{-7}$.

The simple answer that I would go with is, what does it matter? I am not being sarcastic here. Simply put, if a = 0.95 and thus the critical value is at p=0.05, is there really any meaningful difference between p < 0.0001 and p = .000000346?
Basically, I would only give the exact value if it were probative in value. As the exact values of extremely small p-values do not offer any meaningful information on a practical level, especially relative to p<0.0001. Now if you had an a=0.999999, a p<0.000001 would in turn mean that p = 0.000000346 would be reasonable if you preferred exact values. In all likelihood, you're rounding at some point anyway.
With that being said, if I was going to type p=0.000000346 I would opt for p = 3.46E-7 to minimize space. Ultimately, it is a stylistic choice and it is better to err on giving extra information than not enough. But I just pick 0.001 simply to illustrate the low p-value. This works out well for me as I provide the exact p-values if larger than my cutoff value, which makes it clear that those values are extremely small, small to the point that writing it out is not useful.

-1 Your answer shows that you are stuck in the all-or-none Neyman–Pearsonian framework. It offers a particularly unhelpful form of statistical inference for support of scientific inference. You should read a bit more about p-values on this site, and here: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

My answer didn’t speak to all or nothing. It simply stated my view on formatting and that additional precision/decimal places have diminishing returns on information communicated. Going out to 8 decimal places isn’t going to change my conclusions that would’ve been made going out to only 4 decimal places.  If there was a need to go 8 decimal places, so be it.  By your argument the smaller the p value the stronger evidence against null. But at some point the strength is strong enough. Will p= 2.25E-50 have any practical benefit over p < 0.0001? If so, would that benefit outweigh the other data?

Whole genome association analyses regularly result in p-values that you might find to be ridiculously small, but it is still important that the scientists are able to at least rank those results. If you truncate the p-values then that is impossible. Read the linked paper.
